# MultiSignature doubts

Tags: multi-sig

1. Assuming master weight of an account is 1, what is the difference if all threshold weights are 1 or 0 ? In both the cases, operations are authorized.
2. Bump sequence falls under low threshold. Should this be moved to higher threshold since it has the ability to change the flow of account.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no difference, practically.
2. No, because you can consume sequence numbers at low threshold just by using the source account.

Answer (score 1):

1. No difference. 0 === 1.
2. Maybe?